# building api only artifact with maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, modularity

Given our maven projet provides some api for clients to interact with it, those are just few java interfaces which are implemented in interal codebase...

Now if we just build the jar and publish it anyone can see the internal classes we used for implementation, yet we only need few java interfaces to be published (along with few DTO classes maybe)...

Is it possible to pick exactly which java files we want to build jar for and create two artifacts like (product.jar/war and product-api.jar)

Prupose is to limit possible misuse of the code by other teams...

Comment: You can split projects into multiple modules, eg:
project-api, project-jar, project-ejb, project-war etc

Comment: Yes but that sucks, imagine i'll have aproject with just few interfaces and dto classes... i'd do that if no other option is possible...
I hope there is a solution with just pom.xml or with gradle maybe?

Comment: Why it sucks? This is what maven is supposed to do. Besides creating project-api will help to decouple your projects. Also it will be a lot easier to share API with third party in a future.

Comment: Well you'd do the same if you could build 2 artifacts with maven... share the -api artifact with any third party...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is to make separate modules in Maven which represent your modules like:

```
project-api
```

which contains only the interfaces and which can be used by others separately.

```
project-impl
```

one implementation etc.
The above makes testing easier etc. is a good choice with regards to separation of concerns.

Comment: thanks, is it common to do with big projects? my projects gets too big and lot of small teams create dumb dependencies that now is hard to get rid of... thus i want to eliminate possibility that they'll use source that they shouldnt.

Comment: I'm working in a project with 320 modules/120 devs and yes we do this exactly to prevent coupling as you describing.

Comment: @vach I am not sure how this helped you in preventing other teams from misusing the code because you will need to supply them jars for both modules. I have run into something similar where I have to build a separate module for API containing interfaces. But I have not got the full grasp of this concept and how it helps when working with multiple teams.

Comment: the concept is as simple as it can be, if you need to use a client you use client.jar, if you use server.jar there must be someone reputable enough to tell you that you cant do it (code review is a good thing)...

Comment: but if you only have app.jar where everything is present, people will have a tendency to use internal code when they dont like your public api, or if they just feel like it (some "clever" juniors would get into internal code to "optimize" things)...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about securing code instead of maven in general. You can have multi-module maven project but still anyone can download that and decomopile it. 
Few thoughts as Java does have inbuilt mechanism to support this but there are workarounds...some thoughts..

1. When you package a project as jar, don't put.java classes in jar/build. 
   Well the code can be decompiled back to java but at-least u dont
   give .java classes to start with.
2. You can obfuscate your code with
   various    available options. Read bit [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)...
3. At the extereme,
   expose your    api as web services where you define a contract for
   request/response.    No one can see your code...

Comment: I know what you can do with jars and that there are class files only there, and i know about obfuscation... 

What i'm asking is can i build another artifact client-api.jar which will only include few interfaces and any dependencies they have (dto classes)... that jar shall not contain anything else just interfaces...

Comment: I'm not trying to hide my code, imagine  a big project lot of teams working on it, and start to add lot of dependencies (circular sometimes) in their projects... and start using classes they shall never use but copy or reimplement themselfs...